# Firebase does not load value on snapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this React app. When I create this book/WIP object, I want to redirect to the book's page. It can load the book's properties fine but when I try to load the book writer's properties it doesn't. But if I do go to this book's page from elsewhere on the website, the book writer's properties load fine. It's only after I create the book that the writer's properties don't load.

Here are what I think the relevant code is:

NewWipForm.js

```
render() {
    if (this.state.redirect === true) {
      return <Redirect to= {{pathname: '/wip/' + this.state.wipId}} />
    }

    <form className="center-form" 
          onSubmit={(event) => this.createWIP(event)} 
          ref={(form) => this.WIPForm = form}
    >
    </form>
}



createWIP(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
      const WIPsRef = firebaseDB.database().ref('WIPs');
      const WIP = {
        title: this.state.title,
        writer: this.state.userId,
        wc: this.state.wordCount,
        logline: this.state.logline,
        draft: this.state.draft,
        language: this.state.language,
        disclaimers: this.state.disclaimers,
        improvementAreas: this.state.improvementAreas,
        blurb: this.state.blurb,
        additionalNotes: this.state.additionalNotes,
        genres: this.state.genres.split(","),
        types: this.state.types.split(","),
        creationDate: Date.now()
      }
      var newWIPRef = WIPsRef.push(WIP);
      var WIPId = newWIPRef.key;
      this.setState({wipId: WIPId});
    this.addWIPToUser(WIPId)
    this.addOrUpdateWIPIndexRecord(WIPId)
    this.WIPForm.reset()
    this.setState({ redirect: true })
  }
```

WIP.js

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.WIPRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let WIP = snapshot.val()
      if (WIP) {
        this.setState({
          title: WIP.title ? WIP.title : "",
          wordCount: WIP.wc ? WIP.wc : "",
          logline: WIP.logline ? WIP.logline : "",
          draft: WIP.draft ? WIP.draft : "",
          language: WIP.language ? WIP.language : "",
          disclaimers: WIP.disclaimers ? WIP.disclaimers : "",
          improvementAreas: WIP.improvementAreas ? WIP.improvementAreas : "",
          blurb: WIP.blurb ? WIP.blurb : "",
          additionalNotes: WIP.additionalNotes ? WIP.additionalNotes : "",
          writer: WIP.writer ? WIP.writer : "",
          genres: WIP.genres ? WIP.genres : [],
          types: WIP.types ? WIP.types : []
        });
        var promises = []
        var writerRef = firebaseDB.database().ref(`/Users/${WIP.writer}`)
        promises.push(writerRef.once('value')); 
        Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
          snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
            var writer = snapshot.val()
            this.setState({
              writerName: writer.displayName ? writer.displayName : ""
            })
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

so here in `componentWillMount`, what's inside of the `Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {` block never gets executed after creating a WIP(book).

I feel like there's something wrong with my UsersRef. But it seems like I'm turning it off in the right places?

Here's more of the code if you think there's something wrong going elsewhere:

[NewWipForm.js](https://github.com/mayaah/critique-connect/blob/master/src/components/NewWIPForm.js)
[WIP.js](https://github.com/mayaah/critique-connect/blob/master/src/components/WIP.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set my writer in a callback to setState.

New code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData(this.state.wipId)
  }

  loadData(wipId) {
    this.WIPRef = firebaseDB.database().ref(`WIPs/${wipId}`);
    this.WIPRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let WIP = snapshot.val()
      if (WIP) {
        this.setState({
          title: WIP.title ? WIP.title : "",
          wordCount: WIP.wc ? WIP.wc : "",
          logline: WIP.logline ? WIP.logline : "",
          draft: WIP.draft ? WIP.draft : "",
          language: WIP.language ? WIP.language : "",
          disclaimers: WIP.disclaimers ? WIP.disclaimers : "",
          improvementAreas: WIP.improvementAreas ? WIP.improvementAreas : "",
          blurb: WIP.blurb ? WIP.blurb : "",
          additionalNotes: WIP.additionalNotes ? WIP.additionalNotes : "",
          writer: WIP.writer ? WIP.writer : "",
          genres: WIP.genres ? WIP.genres : [],
          types: WIP.types ? WIP.types : []
        }, 
        () => {
          this.getWriterData(this.state.writer)
          .then((snapshots) =>
            snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
              var writer = snapshot.val()
              this.setState({
                writerName: writer.displayName ? writer.displayName : ""
              })
            })
          )
        });
      }
  }

  getWriterData(writer) {
    var promises = []
    this.writerRef = firebaseDB.database().ref(`/Users/${writer}`)
    promises.push(this.writerRef.once('value')); 
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }
```